# Reflux actions global debugging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, refluxjs

Is there a way how to globally `console.log()` all the fired actions in Reflux? Ideally prints theirs parameters at the same time.

Comment: It looks like reflux uses EventEmitter, so you may be able to override something globally there to get the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Cory Danielson said, Reflux uses EventEmitter. And you can insert your own EventEmitter-implementation like this:

```
Reflux.setEventEmitter(require('events').EventEmitter);
```

So you want to inject an EventEmitter constructor there that has debugging enabled, something like this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function DebugEventEmitter() {
  var realEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  var origEmit = realEmitter.emit;
  realEmitter.emit = function () {
    console.log('emitting', arguments);
    return origEmit.apply(realEmitter, arguments);
  };

  return realEmitter;
}

Reflux.setEventEmitter(DebugEventEmitter);
```

This only hijacks the `emit` method which is used to emit events, but you can of course hijack any other method on `EventEmitter` and add logging.

**EDIT**

Since Reflux doesn't pass the action name to the emitted event, here's another solution which is way more hackish, but it should work for debugging purposes.

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');

// Do this before any code is calling Reflux
var origCreateAction = Reflux.createAction;
Reflux.createAction = function () {
  var action = origCreateAction.apply(Reflux, arguments);

  var wrapper = function () {
    console.log(action.actionName, 'called with args: ', arguments);
    return action.apply(action, arguments);
  };

  for (var key in action) {
    wrapper[key] = action[key];
  }

  return wrapper;
};

// Example using actions and triggering them, which logs
// with our wrapper
var Actions = Reflux.createActions([
  'statusUpdate',
  'statusEdited',
  'statusAdded'
]);

Actions.statusUpdate.listen(function () {
  console.log('status update called');
});

Actions.statusUpdate({test: 1});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a partly solution to the question. Result look like this http://postimg.org/image/kwzz3dzz3/, so I can't really see the action name.

Comment: Updated with another way of solving it which includes the action name.